# How to find all complex polynomial $f$ such that $1+f(z^n+1)=(f(z))^n$

Tags: functions, polynomials

**Question:** Let $n\gt1$ be a natural number.  Is there a non-constant complex polynomial $P$ such that $P(x^n+1)=P(x)^n-1$ for all $x$?

I saw this problem about polynomial, here is the question: Find all polynomials $P$ satisfying $P(x^2+1)=P(x)^2+1$ for all $x$.
Solution [here](http://imomath.com/index.php?options=627&lmm=0).

But my problem is different (in particular, it *subtracts* $1$ on the right instead of adding it). How can we solve it?

Comment: What are your thought ? I am tempted to downvote this question..

Comment: @Krokop, your edit asks for an $f$ that satisfies the functional equation for *all* $n$.  My interpretation of the OP's question was that $n$ is arbitrary but *fixed*, and then an $f$ is sought.

Comment: The solution is somewhat off.  In particular, $P(x)=x$ should be a solution, and $P(x)=1$ should not be.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Hum I think your are right, as you are +10k user you may edit it ;P.

Comment: Ah, the solution is okay, it's just very unclear about what symmetry argument it's using.  It basically argues that $P(x)=\pm P(-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The same idea as the linked solution appears to work:

We claim that the solutions are exactly those in the sequence $x, x^n+1,(x^n+1)^n+1,\ldots$

First, let $\omega$ be an $n$-th root of unity.  Substituting $x\mapsto \omega x$, we find that $P(\omega x) = \omega^k P(x)$ for some $k<n$, so $P$ is $x^k$ times a polynomial in $x^n$.  In other words, there is some $Q$ with $P(x)=x^k Q(x^n+1)$.

We have $(x^n+1)^k Q((x^n+1)^n+1) = (x^k Q(x^n+1))^n+1$.  Substituting $y=x^n+1$ gives us $y^k Q(y^n+1) = (y-1)^k (Q(y))^n + 1$.  Reading off the coefficient of $y$ on both sides, we see that $k\in\{0,1\}$.

We have $Q(2)=1$.  If $k=1$ and $Q(a)=1$ for $a\neq 0$, then $aQ(a^n+1)=(a-1)+1=a$, so $Q(a^n+1)=1$.  This gives us an infinite sequence of reals satisfying $Q(a)=1$, so $Q\equiv 1$ and $P(x)=x$.

If $k=0$, then $Q$ satisfies the same equation as $P$, and we can proceed by induction.

Comment: The OP's equation is, in effect, $P(x^n+1)=P(x)^n-1$, not $P(x)^n+1$ on the right.  So it's different in that regard from the problem linked to.  (Note that when $n=1$, the OP's equation is satisfied by polynomials of the form $f(z)=c-z$.)

Comment: I have edited the OP to make the distinction clear.